# How to write a SQL query to get data from several tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need next data from different tables in one report

I need to choose all consultants info from consultant.table

`first_name` & `last_name` & `email` & `phone` from passport.table

[image]

I have `passport_id` in users table

[image]

`Number of consultant` and his `level` from main table of query  consultant.table

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I use mysql table

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output in formatted text (not images). Kindly read [asking SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Use this sql query to get your result:

```
  SELECT  a.first_name, 
      a.last_name, 
      a.email, 
      a.phone, 
      b.level,
      b.user_id
      from passport a 
      INNER JOIN user c 
      ON a.id=c.passport_id
      INNER JOIN consultant b 
      ON b.user_id=c.id
```

[Check this SQL Fiddle for output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f7851/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do an inner or left join. Something like this:

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, a.email, a.phone, b.* from passport a
LEFT JOIN user b
ON a.id=b.passport_id
```

I can't see from your screenshot what the field names are for Consultant and Level hence the `b.*` to pickup all the fields from that table (I assume it IS on that table?). Anyway you can customize this query easily.

Comment: and what about consultant table.Mainly I need data about consultants

Comment: Just add another LEFT JOIN like so:

SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, a.email, a.phone, b.*, c.* from passport a LEFT JOIN user b ON a.id=b.passport_id LEFT JOIN consultant c ON a.id=c.customer_id -> where consultant_id is your foreign key relating to the passport id. However this is uncertain because you didn't post a screenshot of your consultant table so you would have to modify this yourself.


If you need your data output to be "strict" or without nulls then you can use INNER instead of LEFT.

Comment: Your last LEFT JOIN has it as b.id=c.user_id so assuming you really want to join on that, try giving your select statement the individual field names that you want to get and if the primary key is he same you can also assign an alias like so: SELECT a.phone, b.id as userid and so on...